# Is it possible to compare multiple values in AMP Script?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm learning AMP Script and I need to compare a variable with different countries and I'm wondering if, as dynamic block in Marketing Cloud, is it possible to compare a variable with different values. For example:

```
%%[IF @value == 'Spain, France, Canada' THEN]%%
%%=ContentBlockByName(@test)=%%
%%[endif]%%
```

In addition, is it possible to do something similar to:

```
%%[IF @value1 == Spain OR @value2 == 'Latin America' THEN]%%
%%=ContentBlockByName(@test)=%%
%%[endif]%%
```

Thank you so much,
Anna

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this, if there are only a couple comparisons then you can use the OR statement, but if it is a large list, it may make more sense to create a sort of delimited string and utilize the IndexOf() function. (or you can build the delimited string and utilize as a rowset as well).

**Option 1**:

```
%%[ SET @value = AttributeValue("myCountry")

    IF @value == "Spain" OR @value == "Germany" THEN ]%

     YOUR CONTENT

%%[ endif ]%%
```

**Option 2a**:

```
%%[

    SET @value = AttributeValue("myCountry")
    SET @lookupValue = CONCAT("|",@value,"|")
    SET @countries = "|Spain|France|Canada|"

    IF IndexOf(@countries,@lookupValue) > 0 THEN ]%%

     YOUR CONTENT

%%[ endif ]%%
```

if you notice, my delimited string starts and ends with pipes `|` on every entry. This is to prevent partial matches, e.g. day would match not just "day", but also match "today" - giving a false positive. Which is why I created a `@lookupValue` var, which adds in the `|` to the value.

**Option 2b**:

```
%%[

    SET @value = AttributeValue("myCountry")
    SET @countries = "Spain|France|Canada"

    SET @rowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@countries,"|")

    FOR @i=1 TO Rowcount(@rowSet) DO

      set @row = Row(@rowset,@i)
      set @country = Field(@row,1)

      IF @value == @country THEN

        SET @pass = 1

      ENDIF

    NEXT @i 

 IF @pass == 1 THEN ]%%

     YOUR CONTENT

%%[ endif ]%%
```

This one will take the provided delimited string, turn it into a rowset (via BuildRowsetFromString()) and then loop through it comparing the values and if they match, it sets the `@pass` var to 1.  There is then a conditional IF statement afterwards that will display the content if `@pass == 1`.

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington for your answer and your examples! Finally I have chosen the option 2 and it helps me a lot. Have a good day.Anna

Answer (score 0):

Reference the help page ['AMPscript Language Elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm)'

> Use join operators to combine multiple conditions.
>
> AND - Both conditions must be true
>   OR - Either condition must be true
>   The NOT operator reverses the result of any Boolean expression.
>
> NOT - Reverses the Boolean expression
>   Control the expression evaluation using parentheses:
>
> (BooleanExpression AND BooleanExpression) OR (BooleanExpression AND BooleanExpression)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @EazyE! Anna